# WooCommerce - How to add an image next to name of product in Order's ''Add Product'' dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

can't find an answer to it, pretty sure there must be a way via filters to do this but can't find anything related to it.

I've noticed that it pings `admin-ajax.php?term=MyTestQuery&action=woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations`

Is there a way for me to hijack this call and create my own response or something like this?

[image]

As you can see on the image there, it doesn't have an image so sometimes for my customer it's hard since there are a lot of products with similar names.

Is there any filter or action I can use to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_json_search_found_products', 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products');

function woocommerce_json_search_found_products($products) {
    foreach ($products as $product_id => $product_formatted_name) {

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product_id), 'single-post-thumbnail');
        $img_src = isset($image) ? $image[0] : '';
        if ('' !== $img_src) {
            $products[$product_id] = $product_formatted_name . "<img width='30' height='30' src='$img_src'/>";
        }
    }
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: Oh no! I just realized that it does not really work... I mean it works in the way that it shoes it in the dropdown, but then the HTML is raw inside the select once we ''chose'' the option. Do you know how we can make sure the HTML remains formatted properly once the option is selected?